# How can I Insert Additional label on the z-axis in ternary diagram?

Tags: pgfplots, labels

I need help on how I can insert additional label X_{Bi} on the z-axis of the subfigure in my ternary diagram. In the example shown below I can only insert it at a location too far away from the middle of z-axis.Is there anyone who knows how I can put this label at middle (i.e. above the label 'first image' in fig.a) of the z-axis?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label $ $X_{Bi}$
\caption{First Image}
\label{fig:a:first}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Isoactivity curves}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please turn your example into a *minimal* example? There's no need for two axis environments to demonstrate the problem, or for the plots to contain any data, or for the `subfigure` and `figure` environments. If the examples are too large, it deters people from starting work on the problem, because it's just not very enjoyable to have to wade through large chunks of irrelevant code.

Comment: Jake,I have deleted my second figure and its data in line with your comments.However,I still retain certain aspects of what you said may be irrelevant because I think they are still necessary.thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `\node` with the label text. To position it halfway along the z axis, you can use `(zticklabel cs:0.5)` as the coordinate:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           clip=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0
    ]
      \node at (zticklabel cs:0.5) [anchor=north] {$X_{Bi}$};
    \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

---

In the context of your full code: Just add the line

```
\node at (zticklabel cs:0.5) [anchor=north] {$X_{Bi}$};
```

before the `\end{ternaryaxis}` and reactivate the option `clip=false`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };

    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
    \node at (zticklabel cs:0.5) [anchor=north] {$X_{Bi}$};
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{First Image}
\label{fig:a:first}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Isoactivity curves}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks Jake.But this approach will no longer retain the labels at the corners, and the figure's caption.

Comment: @OluseyiAwe: Yes it will, I just removed all those things from the example because they have nothing to do with the core question "How do I add a label under an axis?". I've edited my answer to show how this approach would look with your full code.

Comment: Thanks Jake.I have just confirmed that it works in the full code.

Answer (score 1):

I wrapped your `tikz` images inside a `\stackinset`.  I had to add a few `%` signs to remove spaces and blank lines inside the `tikz`, but other than that, it was as simple as

```
\stackinset{H-alignment}{H-offset}{V-alignment}{V-offset}{inset object}{anchor-object}
```

In your case, I used `c` horizontal and `b` vertical alignment, with a slight negative V-offset.  The label was the inset object, and your `tikz` environment was the anchor object.  Note that `\stackinset` can be nested to add multiple insets to an anchor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots,subcaption}
\usepgfplotslibrary{ternary}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
\usepackage{stackengine}[2013-09-11]
\stackMath
%
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
\stackinset{c}{}{b}{-7pt}{x_\mathrm{Label}}{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sn,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sb,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
    ]
%
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };
%
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };
%
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
  \end{ternaryaxis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\label $ $X_{Bi}$
\caption{First Image}
\label{fig:a:first}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{\columnwidth}\centering
\stackinset{c}{}{b}{-7pt}{z_\mathrm{Label}}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{ternaryaxis}[
           ternary limits relative=false,
           width=7.5cm,
           height=7.5cm,
           ymax=1.0,
           no markers,
%           clip=false,
%         disabledatascaling,
           minor tick num=1,
           grid=both,
           xlabel=Sb,
           xlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:1,0,0)},
            anchor=south
           },
           ylabel=Sn,
           ylabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,1,0)},
            anchor=10
           },
           zlabel=Bi,
           zlabel style={
            at={(axis cs:0,0,1)},
            anchor=north west
           },
  ]
%
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
       (0.9047, 0.0953, 0.0000)
             (0.9019,   0.0883, 0.0098)
             (0.8993,   0.0806, 0.0201)
             (0.8969,   0.0722, 0.0309)
             (0.8950,   0.0630, 0.0420)
             (0.8936,   0.0532, 0.0532)
             (0.8929,   0.0428, 0.0643)
             (0.8930,   0.0321, 0.0749)
             (0.8938,   0.0212, 0.0850)
             (0.8953,   0.0105, 0.0942)
             (0.8975,   0.0000, 0.1025)
    };
%
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
        (0.8209,    0.1791, 0.0000)
              (0.8131,  0.1682, 0.0187)
              (0.8054,  0.1557, 0.0389)
              (0.7980,  0.1414, 0.0606)
              (0.7913,  0.1252, 0.0835)
              (0.7859,  0.1071, 0.1071)
              (0.7823,  0.0871, 0.1306)
              (0.7810,  0.0657, 0.1533)
              (0.7822,  0.0436, 0.1742)
              (0.7859,  0.0214, 0.1927)
              (0.7917,  0.0000, 0.2083)
    };
%
    \addplot3 [black,dashed] coordinates {
            (0.7439,    0.2561, 0.0000)
     (0.7313,   0.2418, 0.0269)
     (0.7186,   0.2251, 0.0563)
     (0.7060,   0.2058, 0.0882)
     (0.6942,   0.1835, 0.1223)
     (0.6841,   0.1580, 0.1580)
     (0.6767,   0.1293, 0.1940)
     (0.6729,   0.0981, 0.2290)
     (0.6734,   0.0653, 0.2613)
            (0.6777,    0.0322, 0.2901)
            (0.6848,    0.0000, 0.3152)
    };
%
\end{ternaryaxis}
  \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\label $ $X_{Bi}$
\caption{Second Image}
\label{fig:a:second}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Isoactivity curves}%
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks.Steven B.S.your suggestion has solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to use R, knitr and the [ggtern](http://www.ggtern.com) package in R (for ternary diagrams), the following can be achieved:

[image: Output]

The following is the full MWE, which utilizes the `tikzDevice`, and the data read from .csv file (ie data.csv, download [HERE](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/27991346/misc/data.csv))

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{helvet}
\renewcommand\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
  <<SETUP,echo=FALSE>>=
    suppressMessages(library(ggtern))
    suppressMessages(library(tikzDevice))
    opts_chunk$set(fig.width=5,fig.height=4)
  @

\begin{figure}[p]
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    %BASE PLOT 
    <<PLOT,echo=FALSE,fig.align='center',dev='tikz'>>=
      df <- read.csv("data.csv")
      base <- ggtern(data=df,aes(y=Sn,x=Sb,z=Bi)) + 
        geom_path(aes(color=Series),size=1) + 
        theme_bw() + 
        theme_anticlockwise() + 
        theme(legend.position=c(0,1),
              legend.justification=c(0,1)) +
        labs(title="Example Ternary Plot")
      print(base)
    @
  \subcaption{Default}
  \end{minipage}%
  \begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    %SHOW ZOOMED PLOT
    <<ZOOM,echo=FALSE,fig.align='center',dev='tikz'>>=
      zoom = base + limit_tern(1,.35,.35,
                               breaks=c(seq(.05,.3,by=.05),seq(.7,1,by=.05)),
                               minor_breaks=seq(.025,1,by=0.025))
      print(zoom)
    @
  \subcaption{Zoomed}
  \end{minipage}
  \caption{Isoactivity Curves, Default and Zoomed}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Note that this needs to be compiled/built in accordance with knitr Rnw dynamic documents. I have used RStudio in this case, which makes it very easy. It is equally easy to do the same using TexStudio, however, you would need to set up the custom command to first knit the documents.